# Get public url from file path in dropbox

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Suppose I have dropbox account, and I have shared folder their, for instance the name of the shared folder is "SampleFolder". And inside that folder I have folder and file hierarchy, which also is shared being inside a shared folder. How can I having SampleFolder url and knowing the file path that I want to download easily get it's url either by Dropbox Core API or just know the way the urls are constructed and construct the url by hand. For instance I want to download file in path SampleFolder/Folder1/Folder2/image.png, how can I get the url of that file knowing only the url of SampleFolder? Let me note that I don't want to login into dropbox, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET) there is a get method for retrieving file by it's path, but it requires authorisation. Basically I want a public place of storing files, and in my code downloading them by their urls.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 8):

*[Addition Aug2017: This method has been disabled by Dropbox for all users. See https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/files-folders/public-folder]*

See https://www.dropbox.com/help/16/en towards the bottom under "Creating a Public folder"

While newer accounts do not have the Public Folder enabled, it is possible to enable it by going to this link when logged into that account: https://www.dropbox.com/enable_public_folder

Then you can follow the path to the file after `https://dl.dropbox.com/u/<user id>/`

Comment: This works great! Even better, now you don't have to rely on the API and key access when mirroring docs and images for a website or email!

Comment: this no longer works for non pro/business accounts. what a shame!

Comment: It is a shame! However, it may be possible to get the Public folder by upgrading to Dropbox Pro for a month, enabling the Public folder, then downgrading the account (make sure to downgrade or you will get charged the next month). I can't say for sure that this will work however.

Comment: @DRC - If it stopped working at some point, it seems to be working now. I just setup a script that builds the public link of the last file dropped into my Public directory. So, may be worth revisiting. :)

Comment: It works great until the present day, but BEWARE!! Joining new TEAMS functionality will change your DB account status!!! You need a "private use" status to use PUBLIC folder links...

Comment: @marcolopes I've been told that you can re-enable the Public folder by visiting https://dropbox.com/enable_public_folder

Answer (score 3):

This used to be possible with Dropbox, at least in the spring of 2012, but it appears no longer to work. Before, if you had a shared folder, you could browse the subcontents of that folder relative to the shared URL, but now, all the subcontents have distinct absolute URLs.

Breaking basic UNIX file path conventions like this is a huge loss in functionality, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Set your link permission to anyone with a link.
try the following link to access it as public static file:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/<docId>/yourfile.ext
```

docId can be found by clicking on Share button of the doc on the dropbox UI.
This the alphanumeric string found after /s/.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, this isn't currently possible in an official or supported way. These shared links don't offer any metadata or API for access like this.

Answer (score 0):

For free users, the Public Folder method for relative paths won't work anymore now. See [here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/files-folders/public-folder).

> As of March 15, 2017 the Public folder in your Dropbox account has been converted into a standard folder. By default this folder is private to your account. This transition will occur automatically.